# How to convert pandas statement to sql queries?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a task that I want to do a task using sql but the problem is I know pandas for making queries in a Dataframe. I have made a mask to query a Dataframe but it is pretty impossible to learn whole sql in few hours.Is there any way to convert pandas statements into sql queries.

My pandas Dataframe query look something like this :

```
    df=df[(df['a']>=something) & (df['b']=='sinf')...and some more]
```

Comment: Maybe help [comparison_with_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like:

```
Select *
From df
Where df.a>=something and df.b=sinf
```